# lararvel uuid as primary key

Tags: laravel, uuid, laravel-events

I'm trying to set an uuid as primary key in a Laravel Model. I've done it setting a boot method in my model as stablished [here](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) so I don't have to manually create it everytime I want to create and save the model. I have a controller that just creates the model and saves it in database.

It is saved correctly in database but when controller returns the value of the id is always returned with `0`. How can I make it to actually return the value that it is creating in database?

**Model**

```
class UserPersona extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     *  Setup model event hooks
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
            $model->id = $uuid->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class UserPersonaController extends Controller
{
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        return UserPersona::create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `keyType` to `string` and `incrementing` to `false`. Since it's not incrementing.

```
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Additionally I have an `trait` which I simply add to those models which have UUID keys. Which is pretty flexible. This comes originally from https://garrettstjohn.com/articles/using-uuid-laravel-eloquent-orm/ and I added some small adjustments to it for issues which I have discovered while using it intensively.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

/**
 * Class Uuid.
 * Manages the usage of creating UUID values for primary keys. Drop into your models as
 * per normal to use this functionality. Works right out of the box.
 * Taken from: http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/
 */
trait UuidForKey
{

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     */
    public static function bootUuidForKey()
    {
        static::retrieved(function (Model $model) {
            $model->incrementing = false;  // this is used after instance is loaded from DB
        });

        static::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->incrementing = false; // this is used for new instances

            if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) { // if it's not empty, then we want to use a specific id
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string)Uuid::uuid4();
            }
        });
    }

    public function initializeUuidForKey()
    {
        $this->keyType = 'string';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since **Laravel 9** you can use build-in traits [`HasUuids`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasUuids.html) or [`HasUlids`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasUlids.html) to support `UUID` or `ULID` for `Eloquent`.

This is sample of model class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelName extends Model
{
    use HasUuids;
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 9 using the built in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids` inside your Model also works.